# Kafka Ensure At Least Once

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, transactions

First project with Kafka, trying to prove that an event will get processed at least once. So far, not seeing evidence that processing is retried.
Structure of dummy app is simple: subscribe, process, publish, commit; if exception, abort transaction and hope it gets retried. I am logging every message.

I expect to see (1) "process messageX" (2) "error for messageX" (3) "process messageX". Instead, I see processing continue beyond messageX, i.e. it does not get re-processed.

What I see is: (1) "process messageX" (2) "error for messageX" (3) "process someOtherMessage".

Using Kafka 2.7.0, Scala 2.12.
What am I missing? Showing relevant parts of dummy app below.

I also tried by removing the `producer` from the code (and all references to it).

UPDATE 1: I managed to get records re-processed by using the offsets with `consumer.seek()`, i.e. sending the consumer back to the start of the batch of records. Not sure why simply NOT reaching `consumer.commitSync()` (because of an exception) does not do this already.

```
import com.myco.somepackage.{MyEvent, KafkaConfigTxn}
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerRecords, KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.common.{KafkaException, TopicPartition}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.util
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

// Prove that a message can be re-processed if there is an exception
object TopicDrainApp {
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  private val subTopic = "input.topic"
  private val pubTopic = "output.topic"
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](KafkaConfigTxn.producerProps)
  producer.initTransactions()
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](KafkaConfigTxn.consumerProps)
  private var lastEventMillis = System.currentTimeMillis
  private val pollIntervalMillis = 1000
  private val pollDuration = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(pollIntervalMillis)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    subscribe(subTopic)
  }

  def subscribe(subTopic: String): Unit = {
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(subTopic))
    while (System.currentTimeMillis - lastEventMillis < 5000L) {
      try {
        val records: ConsumerRecords[String, String] = consumer.poll(pollDuration)
        records.asScala.foreach { record =>
          try {
            lastEventMillis = System.currentTimeMillis
            val event = MyEvent.deserialize(record.value())
            logger.info("ReceivedMyEvent:" + record.value())
            producer.beginTransaction()            
            simulateProcessing(event) // [not shown] throw exception to test re-processing
            producer.flush()
            val offsetsToCommit = getOffsetsToCommit(records)
            //consumer.commitSync()                                        // tried this; does not work
            //producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsetsToCommit, "group1") // tried this; does not work
            producer.commitTransaction()
          } catch {
            case e: KafkaException => logger.error(s"rollback ${record.value()}", e)
              producer.abortTransaction()
          }
        }
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(e) => logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
      }
    }
  }
  private def getOffsetsToCommit(records: ConsumerRecords[String, String]): util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata] = {
    records.partitions().asScala.map { partition =>
      val partitionedRecords = records.records(partition)
      val offset = partitionedRecords.get(partitionedRecords.size - 1).offset
      (partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(offset + 1))
    }.toMap.asJava
  }
}

object KafkaConfigTxn {
  // Only relevant properties are shown
  def commonProperties: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "...")
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "...")
    props
  }
  def producerProps: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true") // "enable.idempotence"
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "...") // "transactional.id"
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3")
    commonProperties.asScala.foreach { case (k, v) => props.put(k, v) }
    props
  }
  def consumerProps: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed") // "isolation.level"
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    commonProperties.asScala.foreach { case (k, v) => props.put(k, v) }
    props
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the correct combination of method calls (subscribe, beginTransaction, process, commit / abortTransaction, etc.), for a demo app. The core of the code is

```
  def readProcessWrite(subTopic: String, pubTopic: String): Int = {
    var lastEventMillis = System.currentTimeMillis
    val consumer = createConsumer(subTopic)
    val producer = createProducer()
    val groupMetadata = consumer.groupMetadata()
    var numRecords = 0
    while (System.currentTimeMillis - lastEventMillis < 10000L) {
      try {
        val records: ConsumerRecords[String, String] = consumer.poll(pollDuration)
        val offsetsToCommit = getOffsetsToCommit(records)
        // println(s">>> PollRecords: ${records.count()}")
        records.asScala.foreach { record =>
          val currentOffset = record.offset()
          try {
            numRecords += 1
            lastEventMillis = System.currentTimeMillis
            println(s">>> Topic: $subTopic, ReceivedEvent: offset=${record.offset()}, key=${record.key()}, value=${record.value()}")
            producer.beginTransaction()
            val eventOut = simulateProcessing(record.value()) // may throw
            publish(producer, pubTopic, eventOut)
            producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsetsToCommit, groupMetadata)
            consumer.commitSync()
            producer.commitTransaction()
          } catch {
            case e: KafkaException => println(s"---------- rollback ${record.value()}", e)
              producer.abortTransaction()
              offsetsToCommit.forEach { case (topicPartition, _) =>
                consumer.seek(topicPartition, currentOffset)
              }
          }
        }
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(e) => logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
      }
    }
    consumer.close()
    producer.close()
    numRecords
  }
// Consumer created with props.put("max.poll.records", "1")
```

I was able to prove that this will process each event exactly once, even when `simulateProcessing()` throws an exception. To be precise: when processing works fine, each event is processed exactly once. If there is an exception, the event is re-processed until success. In my case, there is no real reason for the exceptions, so re-processing will always end in success.

Comment: But how does this work if your producer doesn't have a consumer to reference for the offset...? If your producer just produces, how does it know what the offset should be?

Comment: Here, we assume that we are running a typical app loop: consume-process-produce, i.e. read a message, do some processing, send a message.

Answer (score 0):

according to the reference I gave you , you need to use sendOffsetsToTransaction in the process, but again your consumer won't get the message of the aborted transcation as you are reading only committed transcation

---

Transcations were introduced in order to allow  exactly once processing between kafka to kafka, being said that kafka supported from day one delivery semantics of at least once and at most once,

To get at least once behavior you disable auto commit and commit when processing had finished successfully that way next time you call poll() if you had exception before commit you will read again the records from the last commit offset

To get at most once behavior you commit before processing starts that way if exception happens , next time you call poll() you get new messages (but lose the other messages)

Exactly once is the most hard to achieve in plain java (not talking on spring framework which makes everything easier) - it involves saving offsets to external db ( usually where you process is done) and reading from there on startup/rebalance

For transcation usage example in java you might read this excellent guide by baeldung

https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once

Comment: Thank you for the Baeldung link. I wrote my code after reading that article. It still does not re-process a message. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Your consumer code and the producer code are coupled together, do you even get inside the loop? You start to produce only if you consumed messages? Somethings in the logic does not add up

Comment: But you are missing the point that for at least once you don't need transcations at all

Comment: The code gets in the loop, consumes and prints messages. There are random exceptions which I throw with 10% probability, as a test. When exceptions are caught, the transaction is rolled back (on the producer), but I never see that messageID again, so it looks like it's not getting re-processed. The app has nothing to produce until something has been consumed, no?

Comment: You usually have something that produce and other something that consumes , they are usually different applications "producer" and "consumer" , unless you are talking about kafka streams ...  according to the reference I gave you , you need to use sendOffsetsToTransaction in the process,  but again your consumer won't get the message of the aborted transcation as you are reading only committed transcation

Comment: Your implementation is for exactly once and not at least once

Comment: Try commenting ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed" and I guess you will get your wanted behavior but it against the transaction logic and architecture

Comment: RE: implementation is for "exactly once"- true, but "exactly once" implies "at least once". RE: isolation level: I tried, did not make a difference.

Comment: `it involves saving offsets to external db ( usually where you process is done) and reading from there on startup/rebalance`

This was the missing piece I was trying to understand. So you need to track the offsets yourself in a shared state that the producer can read, and the consumer can mutate? If so, then I can see how that becomes more difficult even with Kafka handling the messy parts of exactly once. How do you avoid the event from being re-consumed during processing...? Do you lock it somehow? Is the producer limited to producing events only as fast as they are processed for offsets?

Comment: Every example, including the one in your link, assumes the producer and consumer are the same process. I've yet to find an example that describes how the producer is supposed to know what the offset is when it has no knowledge about the topic consumers. How is that supposed to work?